# passing parameters to dependent ant target

Tags: ant, callback

i have two ant files

1. mainBuild.xml
2. subBuild.xml

`subBuild.xml` is imported in the `mainBuild.xml`. One of  target from `mainBuild` depends on `subBuild`. I need to pass the argument to the dependent ant target. I dont want to use the `<antcall>` or the `<ant>` tags, as i need the some properties from the

Answer (score 1):

You can define the arguments in the property files, and then read that property in ant like this.

```
<property file="build.start.properties"/>
```

All properties in the property file will be imported in ant, and will be available as ant properties, which you can use in both mainBuild.xml and subBuild.xml.

refer [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Ant/Useseparatepropertyfile.htm) for further reference

Comment: Thanks for the response. My parameter list is dynamic, so that way i will have to recreate the property file every time. Which will be the last thing i wanted. Something like parameter passing would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

[Macros](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) are one way to have re-usable code in ant. You can call them with different argument. Re-using of targets (using property ) may not be desirable as the properties are immutable.